# Discord Modals without TextInputComponent but a Text and Button only

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I just discovered discord-modals, and I've tried using it when asking for information with the TextInputComponent.

After a while, I became curious about achieving this: [image: The message that pops up when deleting a channel.]

The image above is the pop-up message (a modal) that appears when you try to delete a channel. It has a title, a description, and two clickable buttons: "Cancel" and "Delete Channel". This is what I'm trying to achieve using discord-modals.

I'm creating a lottery bot that has its own economy. There's an embedded message and a button in a certain channel:

[image: Embedded Message and Button]

And what I had in mind was after clicking the button, it will show a modal then say "Are you sure you want to pay 50 Euros?" with a clickable button "Confirm" (just like the Delete Channel format).

This might be too ambitious. And yes, I've read the documentation of discord-modals that it only accepts TextInputComponent, but I reckoned that I'll post a question here since it's an interesting discussion whether or not it's possible in the first place (or how can I work around it). Is this possible to code?

Comment: In response to your question of whether what you're asking is possible, the answer is a solid no. Not yet, anyways. It's not a limitation of `discord-modals`, it's a limitation of the discord API itself. Check out the [API docs for modals](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding#interaction-response-object-modal). It only accepts text inputs at the moment.

Comment: I'm unclear on why folk thought the question wasn't worth asking! I mean, there's the "gambling often features predatory business models" thing, but you're asking a pretty dang fair question, @Cifelse! Sorry the community didn't agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible (as of Nov. 4, 2022). The Text Input Component is required when displaying a Discord Modal. Discord might add new features to Discord Modals soon.

Answer (score 0):

Well a better way is to send a message with 2 buttons with the same style as the buttons when deleting a channel:

```js
const row = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
.setComponents(
  new Discord.MessageButton()
    .setLabel('Cancel')
    .setStyle('SECONDARY')
    .setCustomId('cancel'),
  new Discord.MessageButton()
    .setLabel('Confirm')
    .setStyle('DANGER')
    .setCustomId('confirm'),
)
const confirmMsg = await interaction.followUp({
  content : "Are you sure you want to do this?",
  components : [row],
  fetchReply : true
})
```

then listen to it's components with `confirmMsg.createMessageComponentCollector`so that if the message is confirmed or cancelled, you do what you're supposed to do.

With discord-modals you can only ask for text input and not for button interactions like the image